# Error de redireccionamiento al paginar en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas, actualmente me encuentro haciendo un proyecto en laravel 5.2

He estado desarrollando un buscador sencillo, pero he tenido uno que otro problema con la paginación, siempre cuando hago una consulta por el buscador y decido ir a la siguiente página de registros me redirecciona al index del proyecto.

```
<div class="search_box">
    {!!Form::open(['route'=>'buscar.store', 'method'=>'POST'])!!}
    <div class="input-group">
        <input  name="descripcion" type="text" placeholder="Buscar en {{ strtolower($categoria->subcategoria) }} ">
        <input  type="hidden" name="subcategoria" id="subcategoria" value="{{ $categoria->subcategoria }}">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default buscar" type="submit">Buscar</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    {!!Form::close()!!}
</div>
```

Les dejo el controlador

```
 public function store(request $request)
{

    $descripcion = $request->input("descripcion");
    $subcategoria = $request->input("subcategoria");
    $categoria = $request->input("categoria");

    if (is_null($categoria)) {

    $producto = self::join('ped_unidades_medida','vcomp_productos_web1.unidad','=','ped_unidades_medida.unidad_uid')
        ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.marca','forte')
        ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.venta_web','SI')
        ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.subcategoria',$subcategoria)
        ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.descripcion','like','%'.$descripcion .'%')
        ->select(['vcomp_productos_web1.*','ped_unidades_medida.unidad_descripcion'])
        ->paginate(9);

        return view('productos.buscar', ['articulos' => $respuesta, 'categorias' => $categorias, 'destacados' => $destacados, 'categoria'=> $categoria]);

    } else {


    $producto = self::join('ped_unidades_medida','vcomp_productos_web1.unidad','=','ped_unidades_medida.unidad_uid')
        ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.marca','forte')
        ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.venta_web','SI')
        ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.categoria',$categoria)
        ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.descripcion','like','%'.$descripcion .'%')
        ->select(['vcomp_productos_web1.*','ped_unidades_medida.unidad_descripcion'])
        ->paginate(3);

        return view('productos.buscar', ['articulos' => $respuesta, 'categorias' => $categorias, 'destacados' => $destacados, 'categoria'=> $categoria]);

    }

}
```

Y en la vista de productos.buscar tengo el siguiente foreach con paginación.

```
@foreach ($articulos as $articulo)

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="product-image-wrapper">
        <div class="single-subcategory">
            <div class="productinfo text-center ">
                <a href="{{ route('detalle',[$articulo->id]) }}#detalle"><img src="https://www.dyna.com.co/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://190.248.128.69:8002/public/imagenescatalogo/{{ $articulo->codigo }}.jpg&w=350&h=350&far=1&bg=ffffff&q=99"  width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a>
                <h2>{{ $articulo->descripcion }}</h2>
                <p><b>Código: </b>{{ $articulo->codigo }} | <b>Empaque: </b>{{ $articulo->unidad_descripcion }}</p>
                <a href="{{ route('detalle',[$articulo->id]) }}#detalle"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Ver detalle</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endforeach

    {{ $articulos->render() }}
```

Comment: Un compañero me dice que el motivo por el cual pasa eso es por que estoy usando el metodo POST y deberia ser GET, pero no sé por qué.. ¿Alguno me puede explicar? Gracias

Comment: Hola, ¿te valió la respuesta? ¿necesitas más información?

Comment: @Sakrow Si bro! muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que tienes que tener en cuenta es que la paginación se hace siempre mediante `GET` por la sencilla razón de que así puedes ir a la página que quieres, por ejemplo:

`http://midominio/search/?text=mi-busqueda&page=2`

Ahí estarias en la página 2 de la búsqueda `mi búsqueda`. De esta manera es fácil indexarlo y de pasar los parámetros a `Laravel`. Tecnicamente podrias hacerlo por `POST`, pero es más complicado ya que la `URL` es siempre la misma.

De hecho en tu controlador deberías de tener lo siguiente:

`User::paginate(10);`

Así pagina automáticamente `Laravel` un `Model`. En tu caso como es una `query`, deberías de usar el `builder`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator

Aquí tienes una respuesta de `StackOverflow` en ingles que te da un par de ejemplos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090392/how-to-use-pagination-with-laravel-dbselect-query